# change the installed Ubuntu Architecture to x86-64 as the processor supports it

Tags: 18.04

How can I change the installed Ubuntu Architecture to  x86-64 as the processor supports it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) The .iso file for installing Ubuntu 18.04 desktop is 64-bit only.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Will need to install 64 version. Requires backup of data first. Unless you have more than 4GBs of ram, might be best to leave good enough alone.